# SFTP to another server is not sending the file fully and moving to next command before completing the file transfer

Tags: shell, unix, sftp, wait, sleep

I am new to UNIX. Need help in finding the correct approach to send a file.

I have to send a big file 1gb and the time it takes to sftp manually is approx 10 mins, We have tried the below script because we have to login with password.

The problem here is before completely transferring the file. The script come out of the SFTP connection with no error.

Script:
    expect -c "
        spawn sftp ${remote_user}@${remote_host}
        expect \"password\"
        send  ${remote_pswd}\r 
        expect sftp>
        send \" cd ${remote_path}\r \"
        expect sftp>
        send \" lcd ${source_path}\r \"
        expect sftp>
        send \" put ${source_file} \r \"
        expect sftp>
        send \" !sleep 10 \r \"
        expect sftp>
        send \"bye\" "

Log:
        spawn sftp DataStageIM2@192.168.79.15
DataStageIM2@192.168.79.15's password:
Connected to 192.168.79.15.
`sftp>  cd /users/StoreStockManagement/ReferenceData/Inbound`
 sftp>  lcd /staging/oretail/external/data/DSPRD/Output/Pricing/INT340
 sftp>  mput hhtstore_price.dat
 Uploading hhtstore_price.dat to /users/StoreStockManagement/ReferenceData/Inbound/hhtstore_price.dat
hhtstore_price.dat                                                                                                                                           3%  189MB  18.1MB/s
04:31 ETA+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]`

--Here after transferring 3% of the file this script comes out and I cannot see the file there. But when i manually trying the sftp it is working. Only with script it is not copying.

Can some one help here

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code in script:

```
pass ${FileName} in this function 
sftp ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_HOST} cd  ${REMOTE_DIR} mput 
${SOURCE_LOC}${FileName}ls -lrt bye
```

Comment: Hi, you want me to use ls -tr after the file trasnsfer ? The result is null as we cannot transfer the file completly

Comment: what you want exactly,there should be specific message or alert you want ,if file not uploaded  on server. Try this it will workfine . sftp ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_HOST}<<EOF cd ${REMOTE_DIR} mput ${SOURCE_LOC}${FileName}ls -lrt bye

Comment: Firstly I am unable to send the file, need to know why this put command is getting completed and moving to bye without completely copying the file. If manual SFTP works why the script is not working.

Comment: Can we restrict the put command to complete the copying and then move to the next command bye ?

Comment: ok what you can do ,you can check status of command $ echo $?
 like that .it write after mput statement .

Comment: Sir, I want the fix. By knowing the status, all we can do is retry and again it say not copied and this will be in loop. So how to send the file completely ? Do I need to add any wait statement  with put command ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause if this problem. The issue is that the expect command has a time out of 10 seconds, which is too small a window to transfer large files.

Just add this at the top of your script - `set timeout 60`

```
Script: expect -c " set timeout 60
spawn sftp ${remote_user}@${remote_host} expect \"password\" send ${remote_pswd}\r expect sftp> send \" cd ${remote_path}\r \" expect sftp> send \" lcd ${source_path}\r \" expect sftp> send \" put ${source_file} \r \" expect sftp> send \" !sleep 10 \r \" expect sftp>
send \"bye\" "
```

This resets the timeout to 60 seconds and the entire file will be transferred.